# Issue with Seaborn Scatterplot and Categorical Hue Order in PCA Analysis

Tags: seaborn, pca

During the implementation of a Seaborn scatterplot for Principal Component Analysis (PCA), I encountered a KeyError related to the 'Quartile' category. The issue arises in the following line of code:

`sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, size=pca_df['AdultWeekend'], hue=pca_df['Quartile'],  hue_order=pca_df.Quartile.cat.categories, data=pca_df)`

It's important to note that 'Quartile' is a category, not a column in the dataframe. Despite utilizing the .cat.categories accessor to specify the hue order, the code raises a KeyError. I am seeking guidance on resolving this error and effectively incorporating the categorical hue in the Seaborn scatterplot for PCA analysis. Any assistance in rectifying this issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have a `'Quartile'` column in the dataframe, `hue=pca_df['Quartile']` will provoke a key error.  Note that to be suitable for StackOverflow, you should provide minimal code that reproduces the problem, together with test data. For an error, a full error trace (as text) and the versions of the libraries (preferably tested with the newest versions) could help determine what's going on.